# Huawei Ads kit Banner Ad returns Error code 1

Tags: android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ads

I am trying to integrate Huawei Ads kit to my application but it constantly returns me Error code 1 and fails showing any ad. I wish the errors would be more explanatory.

Does anybody have an idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to provide what you've done so far, codes logs etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error code 1 represents invalid slot id or invalid banner ad size.
Please check your bannerview size and ad slot id.

And if you can look at the link below, error codes are self explanatory :
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/ads-sdk-faq

[image: Huawei Ads Kit Error Codes]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used:

```
xmlns:hwads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

instead

```
xmlns:hwads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

But was not any errors in xml file.
So, use the second variant.